# Did China plant 66 billion trees since 2003?

Tags: china

According to [Factocoexist.com](http://www.fastcoexist.com/3046064/in-chinas-great-green-wall-66-billion-trees-are-sucking-up-carbon-emissions):

> Even though millions of acres of rainforest have disappeared around
>   the world over the last decade, there are now more trees and other
>   vegetation on the planet than there were in 2003. One big part of the
>   reason: China's "Great Green Wall," a massive project to line the edge
>   of the Gobi Desert in trees.
>
> **Over the last few decades, more than 66 billion trees have been
>   planted in northern China.** By 2050, the project will stretch along
>   2,800 miles. In theory, it's holding back the desert, though some
>   critics say that plan might not actually work. But the trees are
>   sucking up carbon, and without them, climate change would likely be
>   moving just a little bit faster.

Is it true that China has managed to plant 66 billion new trees since 2003?

Comment: The site doesn't appear to claim that 66 billion trees were planted since 2003. It states that 66 billion trees have been planted in the last few decades.

Comment: Planting 66 billion trees in 13 years would equate to about 13 million a day, every single day. Does that seem a little on the high side to you? It does to me.

Comment: @paxdiablo they do have 1.5 billion people to do the job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No, China has planted approximately 66 billion trees since 1978.

According to the [UN Forum on Forests report](http://www.un.org/esa/forests/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/China_case_study.pdf) dated 2010, China has planted 56.33 billion trees from 1978 to 2009, with 2.48 billion trees being planted in 2009 alone.

> Since 1978, 12.11 billion
>   person-times participated in compulsory tree-planting and 56.33 billion trees were
>   planted. In 2009, 590 million person-times participated in compulsory tree-planting
>   and 2.48 billion trees were planted.

It is likely that the claim is due to a misunderstanding, since extrapolating the tree planting rate from 2009 to 2016 would in fact result in approximately 70 billion trees.

Other sources such as [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/news/international/21613334-vast-tree-planting-arid-regions-failing-halt-deserts-march-great-green-wall) also report that China has planted 66 billion trees since 1978 and not 2003, as claimed.